# Formatting GD::Graph x-axis in Perl

Tags: perl, graph, gd-graph

I'm producing a graph of prices over time.  Because I have dates on the x-axis, I have converted them to days since the epoch. Days since the epoch is not a very clear value to display on the graph so I want to convert them back to human readable dates using the x_number_format option.

But...it doesn't appear to be called as the graph is rendered.

I've created the following test code to demonstrate the problem.

```
use strict;
use GD::Graph::points;

# Generate some random data!
my @x_data;
my @y_data;
for (1...20) {
    push @x_data, $_;
    push @y_data, rand(20) + 10;
}

# This is never called - possible bug!
sub x_format {
    print "X Formatter!\n";
    return " - $_[0] - ";
}

# This gets called for every Y-axis point
sub y_format {
    print "Y Formatter!\n";
    return " - $_[0] - ";
}

my $graph=GD::Graph::points->new(1000,450);
$graph->set(
    y_label             => 'Random numbers',
    y_number_format     => \&y_format,
    x_number_format     => \&x_format,
    x_label             => 'Sequential meaningless numbers',
    x_labels_vertical   => 1,
    x_plot_values       => 1,
);
my @data=(
    [ @x_data ],
    [ @y_data ],
);

open PNG, ">temp.png";
binmode PNG;
print PNG $graph->plot(\@data)->png;
close PNG;

system("temp.png");
```

This test code produces a graph as expected and prints `Y Formatter!` 6 times. One for each point on the y-axis.  However, it doesn't print `X Formatter!` and doesn't format the x-axis.

I have tried formatting the x-axis values more directly with

```
x_number_format     => sub { " - $_[0] - " },
```

That doesn't format the x-axis either.

Am I doing something glaring stupid or is this a bug in GD:Graph?
There are no bug reports for this issue in the [GD::Graph bug page](http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=GDGraph)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inspecting the [source](https://metacpan.org/source/RUZ/GDGraph-1.54/Graph/axestype.pm#L790), I can see that you need to set 
`x_tick_number` to a defined value for the `x_number_format` callback to be called.

So you can try something like this:

```
$graph->set(
    y_label             => 'Random numbers',
    y_number_format     => \&y_format,
    x_number_format     => \&x_format,
    x_tick_number       => 6,
    x_label             => 'Sequential meaningless numbers',
    x_labels_vertical   => 1,
    x_plot_values       => 1,
);
```

According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Graph):

> **x_tick_number**
>   If set to 'auto', `GD::Graph` will attempt to format the X
>   axis in a nice way, based on the actual X values. If set to a number,
>   that's the number of ticks you will get. If set to `undef`, `GD::Graph`
>   will treat X data as labels. Default: `undef`.

Comment: Thank you so much.
I did try looking at the source but couldn't find exactly where to look.

Seems, as suspected, I was missing something quite obvious.